# how to install g++-5 on debian jessie 8.0?

Tags: python-2.7, g++, debian

There was a closed topic here asking the same thing but the solution in it does not work for me...

Basically no matter what I did when I try to:

```
apt-get install g++-5
```

the result will be:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package g++-5
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++-5'
```